# PostgreSQL query is only returning one row when there are two rows that meet the query

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I run the query:

```
select * from table
```

I get 300 results. 2 of which have col_name with the same value: 10348-0. It's of type text.

When I run

```
select * from table where col_name = '10348-0'
```

I expect to be returned two rows return because two rows meet that criteria.

Instead I only get one row who's ID is one less than the other row. I.e. returned row id: 4556 unreturned row id: 4557. The ID column is of type serial integer.

Why am I only getting one row return when I add a "Where" clause to the query?

Comment: Probably some white space. try `where trim(col_name) = '10348-0'`

Comment: That did it! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably there are hidden characters or look-alike characters in the name -- so what looks the same is not necessarily the same.

The most common issue are leading or trailing spaces.  I would suggest that you try finding these using:

```
col_name like '%10348-0%'
```

Another common problem are em-dashes versus en-dashes.  You might also try:

```
col_name like '10348_0'
```

The `_` is the `LIKE` wildcard to match exactly one character.

Comment: This as well as the trim function works. I will accept this answer when I can.